# 64GB phone storage but only 8 available

Tags: internal-storage

I have a pad with 64GB internal storage space. It seems I can only use 8GB at a time. All the apps I tried shows 48GB free storage, but I don't have the chance to access all this memory. Does anybody knows how to solve that issue? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the reasons below:-

1. Maybe the storage was mistakenly partitioned when the manufacturing guys were installing the OS.
2. There's some real problem with the hardware or software. Contact the nearest service centre.
3. The storage is corrupted. Did you do some experiments?

The problem can be something different also. I also had the same problem when I rooted and flashed a custom OS on my phone. The problem was due to some code error in the ROM which made useless partitions in the storage and rendered the storage of no use. If this is the case with your tab, then try flashing a different ROM.

Comment: Don't forget fake Chinese devices also

Comment: Apologies, but I don't have much experience withe the fake chinese phones. If its one of them, probably you'll have to live with 8GB storage.

Comment: They can display 8GB storage but in reality it's less than that

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try to bring some more light into it:   1.- probably, no answer from the manufacturers.                                                    2.- not such a thing exists, manufacturers are in UK and they don't answer.                                                                                                                   3.- not yet, but soon.                                                                                                         4.- I need to learn what is to flash a ROM, I'll keep looking.

Comment: I am trying to create a new partition with the unused space, but I am going slowly because I am learning at the same time. Thanks for you help!!!

Comment: Please move forward with the partitioning stuff only after you are sure that the partitions have have so.e error. Have you tried factory resetting your phone?

Comment: @Guillermo Flashing a rom means that you are installing a different version of Android onto your phone. It's a lengthy process, and since this is not the problem with your phone, you don't need to know much about it.(Still, you can Google about it to satisfy your curiosity)